# Woocommerce Subscriptions - Customer change subscribed product after placed

Tags: plugins, subscription, account, management

Im using Woocommerce, and the Woo Commerce Subscriptions plugin, along with a bunch of others - creating a members only / subscription based ecommerce site.  The best way to highlight what I'm trying to accomplish is this...

Customer comes to our site and orders ***Time Magazine*** for 12 months.  We want to be able to allow our customers, 2 months down the road in their subscription to say "Hey, ***Time Magazine*** isn't working out for me, log into their account, and simply select the order, click maybe a drop-down and select ***Seventeen Magazine***.  This would then obviously change on the admin end, and we would ship them their new choice without fail.  It shouldn't be complicated, as all of our products are the same cost, and not even worried about inventory at this point - just that our customer has the ability to change what they are getting on a monthly basis.

Anyone have an idea of how to approach this correctly, as far as which template to modify - and an idea of how to go about it?  I'd love to just add a widget in the Account Management area of Woo that shows which product they are getting, and let them change it there.. but at this point I'll take anything!

Thanks in advance folks!

Comment: 1. If you've purchased Subscriptions then your first line of recourse should be Woo support.  2. Having said that, I doubt this is possible. I am 90% sure you'd have to first cancel and then create a new subscription, because that's what the payment processors (Stripe, PayPal, etc) would require. I'd love to hear how it might be done if my assumption is wrong though.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i don't believe it should need to affect the payment gateway, as its basically just meta.  when a cust pulls up their order in Woocommerce_account_management - all i need is a widget or drop down of sorts that lists all the available "color" or "magazines" and when they change it, it does on the backend too.  As price for a year is already paid, and im using a variable product for all of this, and only one sku...  it feels so simple yet here i am losing my mind over it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting an exceptional turnaround time from the woothemes zen help desk as directed *helgatheviking* (thanks!) -- turnaround was 12 hours -- they recommend i wait until release 1.4 which is due the beginning of August 2013.  This release will include the ability to upgrade / downgrade subscription mid-term as i was looking for, though im not quite sure that's what i'm after... but will gladly wait and see.  For now, i have a solution I came up with, and maybe this will work for others.

I also use the paid Members plugin from Woo, which controls READ access to pages.  I have created separate pages with only PAID subscription access for each level of membership.  I use a membership SIGN-UP FEE, and now a monthly fee, which is for the product. (example $10 signup fee for a years membership, and $1.99 a month for the product.  Making the product subscription free, enables me to bypass the payment gateways)  After this membership subscription is purchased, it unlocks the page for their viewing, and they can now open a FREE subscription to the "magazine" (no i'm really not selling magazines, but for IP purposes only).  If they want to change their product midway, they need but cancel that free subscription, and open another with the new product... for free.  I control and prevent multiple subscriptions using the Min/Max plugin, as well as Woo Subscriptions built in - one sub at a time feature.  In testing this seems to work flawlessly.

I type this in a fury as I'm now moving at the speed of light again, anybody with questions if i'm not making any sense, please feel free to post and i'll be glad to explain more throughly.

thanks again everyone.